# How do I override a child component in Spartacus?

Tags: typescript, spartacus-storefront

I want to change the html of Spartacus' `ProductListItemComponent`. I tried overwriting this component with a custom one like suggested in https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/customizing-cms-components/

```
ConfigModule.withConfig({
      cmsComponents: {
        ...
      }
    }
  } as CmsConfig)
```

However, I seem to only be able to override the `CMSProductListComponent` like this and not its children (I assume because `ProductListItemComponent` is an internal component and not a CMS one?).

I also tried with outlets but there is no product context available:

```
<ng-template [cxOutletRef]="plOutlets.ITEM_DETAILS" let-product>
  {{ product }} <!-- product is undefined -->
</ng-template>
```

What would be the recommended way to change a `ProductListItemComponent`?

Answer (score 0):

In your module file (eg. `my-custom-list-component.module.ts`, you can override the default `ProductListItemComponent` component with:

```
ConfigModule.withConfig({
  cmsComponents: {
    ProductListItemComponent: {
      component: MyCustomListComponent;
    }
  }
});
```

Your custom template should be provided by this custom `MyCustomListComponent` component you have made.